# How to set up a routing table in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

Consider the following network:

- A number of wirelessHosts (e.g. 3) send traffic to an Access Point which is connected to Router1 via Ethernet
- Router1 is connected to Server1 via Ethernet and it is connected to Router2 via PPP
- Router2 is connected both to Server2 and to Server3 via Ethernet

Now, I want to use the FlatNetworkConfigurator and I am currently trying to set up the Routingfile. I using the inet manual 11.9.3 as reference.

Apparently, the interface-name has to be named. Only Router2 has to Interfaces (eth0 and eth1), but how do I know which interface has which name?

I really don't understand the example given in this chapter: What does the Gateway-entry mean? Is this the IP-address of the Router? How do I know this address? - Can anyone try and explain this in an easy way for a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hierarchical network (as it contains at least one router) so `FlatNetworkConfigurator` should not be used here. Use `IPv4NetworkConfigurator` which has its own logic to explore the network structure and set up even the routing tables if needed. There is a very detailed [tutorial on the INET website](https://inet.omnetpp.org/inet-tutorials//configurator/doc/), how to use it.

Comment: Well, in fact I would advise to always use IPv4NetworkConfigurator, even if the network does not contain a router. Never use FlatNetworkConfigurator as it is deprecated.